# Cannot add file to windows 8 mail app (screen doesnt come up)

Tags: windows-8, email, attachments

I`ve recently reinstalled windows 8.1 from scratch on my asus n550jv laptop, and everything is working good except for this now... when i needed to send a small attachment through email using the mail app, nothing happens.
I click the little paperclip icon on the top right corner when composing or replying an email and nothing happens. the attachment window never comes up.
after repeatedly clicking the icon i noticed that the black attachment window appears for a split of a second coming from the bottom of the screen and imediatelly dissapears.

i have tried running the app troubleshooter, and i have tried reinstalling mail calendar and people.

I dont want to run SFC scannow because i just ran it last week to fix another app related problem >.> (and everytime i do it i lose my themes because of the patch)

any ideas?

EDIT: i have this exact problem
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-ecoms/windows-81-mail-app-cant-access-people-or-attach-a/6452993c-2449-4e44-9450-7aa5582190cb

Still no solution

EDIT 2: ran SFC /SCANNOW twice, reinstalled several times, reseted windows store, reinstalled with windows power shell.
(sfc fixed a problem with currency converters not updating btw)

EDIT 3: the same happens if i click the "To" field when composing an email. Instead of People app coming up, it just flashes for a split of a second and nothing happens. (People app works fine if i start it from the start menu)

EDIT 4: created new local account, issue persists on all accounts in this computer.

FIXED: Windows Updates fixed the problem as of April 2014

Comment: The first thing I would do, is uninstall and reinstall the application, this is a mandatory troubleshooting step.

Comment: already did. See Edit 2

Comment: Does the dialog stay up when you forgo the mouse and use alt+I ?

Comment: im afraid not. the same issue still happens (i didnt even knew about the alt+I command. thx for that lol)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's April's latest updates to the windows 8 mail app fixed the problem.